# How to get Distinct values in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

How to get Distinct values in d3.js.

Here is my code

```
var bar = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(d3.values(nodes.filter(function(d){return d.group==1;})).sort(function(a, b){return b.value - a.value;}))
;

bar.enter().append("rect")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.value > 0 })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(1200," + i * barHeight + ")"; })
   // .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(850," + i * barHeight + ")"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return width - x(d.value) ; }) 
    .attr("y",56)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    //.attr('class', function(d) { return d.node_name;} ); 
    .attr('class', function(d) { return "bar"+d.node_name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/gi, "");} );
```

Here is the sample of data

```js
var nodes = [{
  node_name: "insider.webmetro.com",
  name: "insider.webmetro.com",
  group: 1,
  value: 15.54,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "internetmarketing.webmetro.com/About.htm",
  name: "internetmarketing.webmetro.com/About.htm",
  group: 1,
  value: 15.54,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com",
  name: "webmetro.com",
  group: 1,
  value: 606,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/About.htm",
  name: "webmetro.com/About.htm",
  group: 1,
  value: 19.5,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/about1.htm",
  name: "webmetro.com/about1.htm",
  group: 1,
  value: 15,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/blog",
  name: "webmetro.com/blog",
  group: 1,
  value: 212,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/blog/pay_per_click/amazing_ppc_tactics_and_bid_simulator_at_smx_advanced.aspx",
  name: "webmetro.com/blog/pay_per_click/amazing_ppc_tactics_and_bid_simulator_at_smx_advanced.aspx",
  group: 1,
  value: 42,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/blog/search_engine_optimization/importance_of_latent_semantic_indexing_in_seo.aspx",
  name: "webmetro.com/blog/search_engine_optimization/importance_of_latent_semantic_indexing_in_seo.aspx",
  group: 1,
  value: 28,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/brochure",
  name: "webmetro.com/brochure",
  group: 1,
  value: 212,
  type: "circle"
}, {
  node_name: "webmetro.com/careers",
  name: "webmetro.com/careers",
  group: 1,
  value: 15.54,
  type: "circle"
}];
```

Comment: But the nodes array you have shared does not contains any duplicated values. ????

Comment: I using `value` field from nodes array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got right, you want distinct objects based on `object.value`.

To find object based on it's properties, you can use following function:

```
function findByValue(source, value) {
    return source.filter(function( obj ) {
        return +obj.value === +value;
    })[ 0 ];
}
```

Include it in your `filter` function like this:

```
var result = nodes.filter(function(element_value, element_index, element_array){return element_value.group==1 && element_array.indexOf(findByValue( nodes, element_value.value )) === element_index });
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j3vST/354/ - you will see in console log that only distinct objects (based on `object.value` are returned).

Comment: as indicated in several similar answers, `d3.map(data, function(d) {return d.value;}).keys()` is working.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure what exactly you are after. Are you are after the distinct elements of the `nodes` array, or the distinct `values` field from the `nodes` array?

Since there are no duplicated entries in the array itself, I assume you are refering to the unique `values` field. In that case, you can use the following method to retrieve the unique(distinct) values:

```
function unique(x) {
    return x.reverse().filter(function (e, i, x) {return x.indexOf(e, i+1) === -1;}).reverse();
}
```

and to obtain the unique values, you can do:

```
var unique_values = unique(nodes.map(function(d){return d.value}))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const distinctValues = [...new Set(data.map((d) => d.column))]
```